# Geopandas readfile zip gives fiona.errors.DriverError:not recognized as a supported file format

Tags: python, zip, geopandas, fiona

I try to read_file with geopandas. I want to read a zip file. The zip file is sended with a request and type is: **django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile**

my code is as follows:

```
fileobject = request.FILES['map']
gdf = geopandas.read_file(fileobject)
```

when i try to read_file i get this error:

```
fiona.errors.DriverError: '/vsimem/00397ff2afaa42b28e7bea85d630588d/00397ff2afaa42b28e7bea85d630588d' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

iam using the following versions
**fiona==1.8.18
geopandas==0.8.2**,
can anyone help?